# Angular JS how to filter by variable of JSON

Tags: angularjs

**index.html**

[image]
**test.json**

[image]
I want to be able to dynamically filter by the user clicking the button repersenting who's specific phone number they would like to see instead of using "filter: {Name: 'Bob'}" only showing Bobs info but I have not been able to find a way to use a variable in place of 'Bob'. I have provided the code in images.

Answer (score 1):

Plunker was right in how I use a variable in my filter, I just did what Shb said in the comments as well so my buttons were out of scope and I just adjusted the tags ng-app and ng-controller to the body and Punkers solution to the filter works. Thanks guys something I should have easily seen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('DB', []);
    app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
      $scope.db = [{
        "Name": "Bob",
        Phones: ["555-555-5555", "555-556-5556"]
      }, {
        "Name": "Jim",
        Phones: ["555-555-5554"]
      }];

      $scope.filterName = 'Bob';

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="DB" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="filterName='Bob'">Bob</button>
  <button ng-click="filterName='Jim'">Jim</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phones in db | filter: {Name: filterName}">
      {{phones.Phones}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('DB', []);
    app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
      $scope.db = [{
        "Name": "Bob",
        Phones: ["555-555-5555", "555-556-5556"]
      }, {
        "Name": "Jim",
        Phones: ["555-555-5554"]
      }];

      $scope.filterName = 'Bob';

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="DB" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="filterName='Bob'">Bob</button>
  <button ng-click="filterName='Jim'">Jim</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phones in db | filter: {Name: filterName}">
      {{phones.Phones}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FcvPUtY6jIA1ZvH2udZm?p=preview)

Comment: The variable filterName filters Bob because of initializing the variable with Bob but when I press the button it does not change the variable, unless it is and it isn't displaying the change in value.

Comment: In your code you have placed buttons before `ng-app`. Place buttons inside 

    `<div ng-app="DB" ng-controller="controller">...<button ng-click="filterName='Bob'">Bob</button>
      <button ng-click="filterName='Jim'">Jim</button>`

Comment: Thank you Shb! That was 100% was my error! This is my first time using angular and it is weird to have to think of scope in html but that is my stupid fault lol